# Proving that every arc in a normal space $X$ is a retract of it using commutative diagrams and a different version of Tietze extension theorem.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory, proof-explanation, retraction

Here is the question:

Let $X$ be a normal space and let $A \subseteq X$ be an arc, with inclusion function $i: A \rightarrow X,$ Since $A$ is an arc, we have a homeomorphism  $\bar{\alpha} : I \xrightarrow{\cong} A;$ Let's write $f_{A} =\bar{\alpha}^{-1}: A \rightarrow I.$ Prove the following "Let $X$ be a normal space. Then every arc $A$ in $X$ is a retract of $X$." by analyzing the following diagram:

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> A @>{f_{A}}>> I\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
>  X @>{f}>> I
> \end{CD} \longrightarrow A$$

Where the first vertical arrow is the inclusion map, the second vertical arrow should not exist but I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams and the last horizontal arrow on the right (that goes into $A$) should start from $I.$ and the arrow that has the function $f$ above it should be dotted line because we are searching for this function $f.$

**My thoughts:**

I know that:

1- -A space $X$ is said to be normal if all singleton sets are closed and if for any two disjoint closed subsets $A, B\subseteq X$ there are open sets $U,V \subseteq X$ such that $$A \subseteq U, B \subseteq V, \textbf{ and } U \cap V = \emptyset.$$

2-**Definition**

An arc in a topological space $X$ is a subspace $A \subseteq X$ that is the image of an injective continuous function $\alpha : [a,b] \rightarrow X$ from a closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ to $X.$ If $X$ is Hausdorff, then the map  $\bar{\alpha} : [a,b] \rightarrow A$ obtained from $\alpha$ by restricting the target is a homeomorphism.

The homeomorphism $\bar{\alpha}$ enables us to identify the two endpoints of an arc $A \subseteq X-$ they are the points $\bar{\alpha}(a)$ and $\bar{\alpha}(b).$

**Arcs differ from paths in 2 ways:**

1- Arcs are subsets, not functions.

2- Arcs are not even just **images of paths:** an arc must be homeomorphic to $[a,b],$ while the image of a generic path can be very different from $[a,b].$

3- I am allowed to use "Tietze Extension Theorem" statement without proving it. So by it I am given that $f \circ i = f_{A}.$ Here is the statement I am allowed to use:

Let $X$ be a normal space and let $A \subseteq X$ be a closed subspace with the inclusion map $i: A \rightarrow X.$ If $J \subseteq R$ is any closed interval and $ f_{A}: A \rightarrow J$ is any continuous function, then there exists a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow J$ making the following diagram commutes:

> $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> A @>{f_{A}}>> J\\
> @VVV @VVV \\
>  X @>{f}>> J
> \end{CD} $$

Where the first vertical arrow is the inclusion map, the second vertical arrow should not exist but I am not skillful in drawing commutative diagrams.  and the arrow that has the function $f$ above it should be dotted line because we are searching for this function $f.$

4- To prove that every arc $A$ is a retract of $X,$ I know that I have to prove that there exists a continuous function $r: X \rightarrow A$ such that $r\circ i = id_{A}$ where $i:A\rightarrow X$ is the inclusion map.\

**My idea is:**

Since $X$ is normal, $A$ is an arc, $I$ is a closed interval and since $\bar \alpha$ is a homeomorphism then $f_{A}$ exists and is continuous and then by Tietze extension theorem there exists a continuous function $\bar{f}_{A}: X \rightarrow I$ such that $f = \bar{f}_{A} \circ i = f_{A}.$ then if I compose on both sides with $\bar \alpha,$ I will get that the RHS is the $id_{A}$ but then the LHS will be $\bar{f}_{A} \circ i  \circ \bar \alpha.$ I need to take my retraction $r$ to be $\bar{f}_{A} \circ \bar \alpha$ but how can I do that? The inclusion function $i$ is inbetween. Could anyone help me in solving this situation please?

5- I understood from this link [A retract in normal space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2129100/a-retract-in-normal-space)   that Urysohn's Lemma will be used but I do not understand why we should use it? Also my version of Tietze theorem does not include extention of the codomain. So how will my proof be different from the one I mentioned in the above link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $I$ is a retract of $\mathbb R$, with retract $r:\mathbb R \rightarrow I$ we can always extend a function $f: A \rightarrow I$ to $X \rightarrow I$. Just extend $f$ to $\tilde f: X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and then $r \circ \tilde f$ extends $f$ with the appropriate codomain.

Your retract $X \rightarrow A$ is constructed using the extension of $f_A: A \rightarrow I$, denoted $g:X \rightarrow I$, then $\tilde \alpha \circ g$ will be the retract $X \rightarrow A$ you are looking for. This is because $(\bar \alpha \circ g) \circ i = \bar \alpha \circ f_A = \text{id}_A$ by definition so $\bar \alpha \circ g$ really is a retract $X \rightarrow A$.

Comment: What about my questions about the other proof?

Comment: What are the mistakes in my idea ?

Comment: Your idea is wrong because $\bar f_A \circ \bar \alpha$ is not a map $A \rightarrow X$, the composition is not even defined since $\bar \alpha$'s codomain, $A$, is not equal to $\bar f_A$'s domain, $X$. And I made a major mistake in my proof $r: \mathbb R \rightarrow I$ not $I \rightarrow \mathbb R$, my bad.

Comment: It's all part of the absolute extensor = absolute retract idea.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  what is this idea?

Comment: what is the explicit definition of the retraction $r$ in your first line?

Comment: $r(x) = 1$ if $x \geq 1$, $r(x) = 0$ if $x \leq 0$ and $r(x) = x$ if $x \in [0,1]$ @Smart20

Comment: @Smart20 A space $X$ is an absolute extensor for normal spaces iff for all $Y$ normal, $A \subseteq Y$ closed, and $f: A \to X$ continuous, we can extend $f$ to $Y$ continuously. A space $X$ is an absolute retract (for normal spaces) if whenever we embed $X$ as a closed set of a normal space $Y$ via ($i$ say), $X$, then $i[X]$ is a  retract of $Y$. These classes of spaces coincide (classic fact). $I$ is an absolute extensor due to Tietze. etc. See Hu's book on absolute retracts.

Comment: I understand the details of how you created the retract of $X$ into $A$ .... but the general idea is not that much clear for me ..... could you please explain what you did in words?@NoelLundström

Comment: Did you @NoelLundström used Tietze theorem twice?

Comment: No, I used it only once. I used it to create $g$ from $f_A$.

Comment: @NoelLundström in your second line why the codomain of $\overline{f}$ changed to $\mathbb{R}$? my version of Tietze extends only the  domain and nothing happen to the codomain.

Comment: Are not you using  Tietze extension theorem in your first 2 lines? or what are you using?

Comment: What was the importance of using the information of $I$ is a retract of $\mathbb{R}$? why did you need it in your proof?

Comment: Because if $J \subset \mathbb R$ is any subset of $\mathbb R$ then not every function $A \rightarrow J$ extends to a function $X \rightarrow J$. But if $J$ is a retract of $\mathbb R$ this is the case.

Comment: What about my remaining questions?

Comment: Is not your last comment contradicting the statement of Tietze I am using? as the statement did not say this.

Comment: I think what you are saying in the first 2 lines is satisfied because $A$ is an arc by assumption.